# Let $F(x)=\int_0^x {e^{e^t}}dt$, what is $\int_1^2\frac{e^x}{x}dx$ in terms of $F$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have this question that I have been struggling upon:

Let $F(x)=\int_0^x {e^{e^t}}dt$, what is $\int_1^2\frac{e^x}{x}dx$ in terms of $F$?

Should I evaluate $\int_1^2\frac{e^x}{x}dx$ first? It seems hard to directly evaluate it...

**Update:**

$F(x)=\int_0^x {e^{e^t}}dt$

Let $u={e^t}$

$du={e^t}dt$

$dt=\frac{du}{u} $

Change the upper and lower limits:
$t=o\to u=e^0 =1; t=x\to u=e^x $

$F(x)=\int_0^x {e^{e^t}}dt = \int_1^{e^x}\frac{e^u}{u}du $

$e^x =2$ and $x=ln(2)$

So $\int_1^2\frac{e^x}{x}dx =\int_1^{e^{ln(2)}} \frac{e^x}{x}dx = F(ln(2))$

Comment: Your definition of $F(x)$ does not depend on $x$.  For example, maybe the upper limit should be $x$ instead of $e$.  You are expected to transform the second integral in a way that it looks like $F(x)$ somehow.  The fact that the lower limit of the integral you want is $1$ and the lower limit of the $F(x)$ suggests $u=\ln x$ to me.

Comment: Hint: "Evaluate" the integral $\int \frac{e^x}{x}\,dx$, letting $x=e^t$. Then $dx=e^t\,dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple substitution, which you should be able to find, and the second integral is $F(ln(2))$

Comment: liya7, my original answer was incorrect.  Please have a look at the revised answer, which I believe is correct now.